# Automatic registration for anonymous node authors

Tags: nodes, users

I need anonymous users  to be automatically sent drupal 'welcome' link  when they create nodes (it's required to enter email and to create login when creating nodes). So AFTER the node is created, the user can go on with registration.

Comment: So far, you simply described what you want to achieve, but you didn't ask any explicit question. Where are you stuck at? What did you try, and why it didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how easily you would be able to do this, but you might be able to do this using rules.

Have a look at [Inline Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_registration).  You can configure quickly to attach a registration form to the node creation form.

Comment: I'd be interested in how you'd do this with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Can you update this answer to include a rule (in Rules export format) that could be used for this? About **Inline Registration**: can you explain how that module helps to answer this question, eg how it should be configured to answer this question here? PS 1: you may also want to include a relevant "quote" from the project page(s) from the modules you mentioned (to make your answer look less like what's called a "link only" answer). PS 2: what if this question is about D8 (or maybe D6)?

Comment: Inline Registration did it

Comment: Hi Peirre....spent the day ill in bed yesterday, so I have only just looked at this.  I did say it might be possible, I had not actually explored it.  You can create rule that fires whenever a node is created, and you can send an email.  I guess you could copy the welcome email from the config and send that.  You would need to collect an email address upon the node creation...so this would have to be added to the content type.  You could use the field permission module to make it appear for certain users.  It wouldn't be full proof, and I think I wend up sending a registration link email.

Comment: Inline registration module literally attaches a user registration form to the node/add form.  Struggling at the moment with working out how to customize it myself, you can literally just bolt it onto the top or bottom of the form...I haven't worked out if you can integrated with the field groups module yet.  It doesn't do exactly what the user was looking for, but gives pretty close functionality.  I think if you really wanted to the achieve the usecase above, you would have to custom code something else.  Although the Anonymous Publishing module seems to offer what was required.

Comment: ..the way I see it, why spend loads of time coding something up, when someone else has already done it for you!?  I hope that gives somes answers anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not impressed by this answer, even not after also taking into consideration what you added in your comments below it. Don't worry, I rarely downvote ... I prefer to provide constructive critique like in this comment, hoping that it will help you to really improve your answer (if you do, I might upvote it).

Comment: Hi Pierre – thanks for the comments.  I understand what you are saying.  I think that this was more of a discussion really.   

Kiamlaluno clearly said that they thought:

“Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.”

Comment: So what the question was, wasn’t fully clear.   However Timur did say that the inline module solved the problem.  As I highlighted, there are a lot of modules which already do required functionality.  Correct me if I am wrong but the issue that Timur was trying to overcome was getting site visitors to actually create an account after they create a node.  I feel that the inline registration module provides this functionality for Drupal 7.  

More importantly the person who asked the question in the first place (Timur), said:

“Inline Registration did it – Timur Kutuev”

Comment: If you mean that I didn’t answer how to do with rules, you are quite correct I didn’t.  I would need to research it.  But since other modules already provide the functionality in a variety of ways, why wouldn’t you use one of those?

Comment: I think maybe this post would have been better in the drupal.org forum - “post installation”.  I don’t claim to be any kind of drupal expert.  But try to help people out if I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got some success using the [HybridAuth Social Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module. This is pretty easy to configure. I think there are a couple of videos online for how to configure it. I have it configured for Facebook, and it's a one click registration for the user. Not sure about the other providers though. I also wonder about site security implications and bots. But I seem to have been OK so far.

You could also look at [Anonymous publishing](https://www.drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing) module. This may do what your looking to do as well.

Comment: apparently I am not allowed to post more than 2 urls at the moment..so that was my way around it.